# Badges awarded by page views (Famous Question)

Tags: discussion, badges, view-badges

The (gold) Famous Question badge has the description: "Asked a question with 10,000 views."

Aren't all users who ask a question going to acquire this badge eventually? I mean, it would have to be something seriously obscure to not pick up a few pageviews every-so-often and even very mediocre questions will get significant pageviews just from people looking to avoid duplicates.

It seems to me, anything based on pageview counts should apply a rolling window to the criteria. So the badge description would be "Asked a question with 10,000 views in 60 days" or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps everyone will, but some questions gain views so slowly that it is unlikely. But it is also more likely that things voted down to oblivion will get deleted and therefore will not get viewed anymore.

In a theoretical world where everyone posts questions and at least one question makes it through, you could be right, but in reality this doesn't necessarily have to be the case.

I also don't really understand why we give badges for page views anyway, but alas.

Comment: Because it is kind of an achievement to having 10,000 people see your question.

Comment: If 10,000 people take time out of their day to look at a question and how people answer it, it is a good, relevant question that will be worthwhile for people to find. We wouldn't be where we are technologically without people asking the right questions.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that all users will eventually get the badge, but a good chunk of them will. However, I disagree that there should be a time limit on the badge -- there's no inherent value to the badge (outside of our flair), and it's a good way to let long-time users get in on otherwise very-hard-to-obtain gold badges.

Answer (score 1):

Date 19 September 2015

Proof that **not** all questions on Stack Exchange eventually reach 10,000 views is the OP's question itself. In just over six years, it has been visited a mere <del>148</del> <del>153</del> 163 times.

P.S: 
I'm searching through the archives because I think questions that reach 100,000 views deserve special recognition.

Comment: Your bump gave it some extra views, but doubt it will ever reach 1000.