# Should I get a Famous Question for this?

Tags: support, badges, view-badges

I just noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875033/getters-setters-in-java) got 10k views.
Does this mean it's a Famous Question?

Comment: Should you? Probably not because it's not an exceptional good question, it just happens to have a title that many people google (while probably looking for something else). Will you? Yes, soon.

Comment: @Kop I see what you mean(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14234/badges-awarded-by-page-views-famous-question), and it makes sense. Just like in real life, not all things 'famous' are exceptionally good. That's why, im my opinion, 'Great Question' is a tag suited for that (good questions, not famous questions). famous can be good, but doesn't need to, great must always be great, but not necessarily famous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The stats on the right-hand side of the question itself say "viewed 9,620 times". The stats on your user page say "10k" due to rounding.

Comment: I see 9.620 when I hover 10kview...should've done that earlier. Thanks!