# Raise criteria for famous question gold badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, views

I see so many users with a single gold badge **"Famous Question"** on stackoverflow.
Why is the criteria to get the badge only 10k views? Stackoverflow is a very popular site. Its ranked very high in countries like India.
For a site like stackoverflow, which attracts so many visitors a day,  this badge doesn't seem rare to get for a noteworthy question.

Why not raise the criteria to 20,000 views or even more?

Comment: Related: [Badges awarded by page views (Famous Question)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14234)

Comment: I've seen that question. I'm requesting to increase the view count.

Comment: The criteria is *time*.  Wait long enough and you'll get enough views.

Comment: @D3EP4K: That question asks for similar increases. The answer is still the same: *No*.

Comment: 10k views are still A LOT for a question.

Comment: Why do you feel the badge should be harder to get? Where's the harm in people actually achieving the badges?

Comment: @AnnaLear Since thats what is mentioned on the site. "Gold badges are rare". And indeed, other badges are comparatively rare to get. For this badge, you ask a good question and never visit the site again.

Comment: I didn't expect so many downvotes. I understand it's a possible duplicate. I'm not going to get a "famous question" badge sure, for this one.

Comment: Roughly 48000 people out of 1202458 who ever asked a question on Stack Overflow have the "Famous Question" badge. I don't think we have to worry about it being too common just yet. :)

Comment: 92.9k awarded for famous question.. which is way ahead of runner up great answer(9.6k awarded). It just stands out in the list. http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold

Answer (score 5):

For other stack exchange sites, such as Christianity, 10,000 views is exceedingly difficult.  We're nearing three years, and [only 18 have been awarded to date](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question).  This same level that you feel is too low on SO would be too high on C.SE.

Comment: Not really a reason since those criteria could probably be differ between sites.

Comment: Well, in that case, the criteria should be relative to the popularity.

Comment: @ThiefMaster That's an even harder sell for us since we're trying to make the sites behave as close to the same across the network as possible.

Comment: @D3EP4K So as the site grows, the badge becomes harder to get? That doesn't seem fair to folks who join up later.

Comment: @AnnaLear hmm.. valid argument.

Answer (score 5):

10k views for a *single question* are a lot no matter how big Stack Overflow is.

I just checked my highest-viewed questions:

- [Merge multiple lines (two blocks) in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760326/merge-multiple-lines-two-blocks-in-vim) - 70k views. It was #1 on /r/programming and also very high on the reddit frontpage.
- [Hashing a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884066/hashing-a-python-dictionary) - 11k views. The question is 2.5 years old and the first result when [googling for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=hashing%20python%20dictionary).
- [JavaScript: Disable text selection via doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117466/javascript-disable-text-selection-via-doubleclick) - 10k views. 3 years old. [#1 in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20doubleclick%20selection).
- [List of ANSI color escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842424/list-of-ansi-color-escape-sequences) - 6.5k views. 2.5 years old. [#2](https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi%20color%20sequences)/[#4](https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi%20colors) in google.

So unless a question gets an external boost (mostly reddit/hackernews) it takes a long time to reach 10k views.

Comment: The universe is expanding with an ever increasing rate :D .